# How to forward packet from eth0 to a tun/tap device?

Tags: networking, ipv6

Here is the topo:   HostA(eth0) ---- (eth0)HostB

I have created a tun/tap device on HostB, for say tun0 or tap0. When eth0 of HostB receives a packet from HostA, maybe a ICMPv6(NS, echo request, etc.) or a UDP/TCP packet(encapsulated with IPv6 header), I want to forward this packet from eth0 to tap0. After doing something to this packet, I also want to send a reply back to HostA, through tap0 and eth0.

I cannot find a way to do that, can some one help me or give some hints?

Comment: Do you want to write a program that forwards packets, or do you want to configure the operating system to do the forwarding?

Comment: Both are ok, I just want to forward all packets from real network adapter to tun device, no matter what way is.

Answer (score 0):

This is an *extremely* basic routing question, probably unsuitable for Stack Overflow.

You need something like this on Host B:

```
HostB# sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
HostB# ip -6 addr add 2001:db8:0:0::1/64 dev eth0
HostB# ip -6 addr add 2001:db8:0:1::1/64 dev tun0
```

Then on Host A:

```
HostA# ip -6 addr add 2001:db8:0:0::2/64 dev eth0
HostA# ip -6 route add default via 2001:db8:0:0::1 dev eth0
HostA# ping6 2001:db8:0:1::2 # <-- should work if that host exists on tun0
```